# Get X Y Z from PolygonZ

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, polygon

I opened a polygon shape file to read the coordinate (X, Y, Z) of vertices using the following code. The coordinates of one of the triangles are show below in the picture. My question is how I get X Y Z from the PolygonZ format? I tried `.zAt(0)`, but it works for linestring. The PolygonZ has 3 points and each point has X, Y and Z

```
layerT = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(tPolygonLayer)[0]  
featsT = [feat for feat in layerT.getFeatures()]   
geom=featsT[0].geometry()
```

[image]

Comment: Please use code formatting, not screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the code snippet below. After calling `geometry()`, we can string together calls to `constGet()` and `vertices()`, then traverse the vertex iterator (or use list comprehension to store the vertices in a list) and call `x()`, `y()` and `z()` on the vertex point objects to access the X, Y & Z values:

```py
layerT = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('tPolygonLayer')[0]  
feat = [f for f in layerT.getFeatures()][0]
verts = [v for v in feat.geometry().constGet().vertices()]
for v in verts:
    print(v.x(), v.y(), v.z())
```

You could also use:

```
feat.geometry().constGet().exteriorRing().zAt(0)
```

to access the Z value of a vertex at the given index.

Comment: The code snippet works great. Thanks.

Comment: No worries @RRCH, glad it helped. If it solved your problem, please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside it.

Comment: Just to round out this answer - you could also use feat.geometry().get().exteriorRing().zAt(0)

Comment: Hi @ndawson. Thanks for the comment- I have edited it into my answer for completeness. I modified it slightly though since I came across some weird behaviour while testing- `feat.geometry().get().exteriorRing()` returns `None`. Removing `exteriorRing()` and just calling `get()` crashes QGIS! I tested with both a geopackage & a shapefile with geometry type Polygon25D. It works fine with `constGet()` though- any idea why?

Comment: Ah, it's python's garbage collector kicking in prematurely - this would also work `g=f.geoemtry().get()` `g.exteriorRing().zAt(0)`

Comment: Ah, ok- interesting. So keep a reference to the abstract geometry object by storing it in a variable? Cheers @ndawson